# How to get decrement forloop.counter in django template?

Tags: django, templates, decrement

I'm new to django and python,

and not able to find how to get decrement `forloop.counter`.
(no matching result in google & stack overflow.)

I tried "forloop.counter-".

Please help me.

```
-in_a_django_template.html
    START
    {% for value in list %}
        {{ forloop.counter- }}
    {% endfor %}
    END

What I expected:
    START
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**`forloop.revcounter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```
{% for value in list %}
    {{ forloop.revcounter }}
{% endfor %}
```